# How do I mirror an individual file from a Gitlab repository to a Github repository?

Tags: github, gitlab, mirror

My collaborators are running a Gitlab repository. My own code in Github needs to access one of the files in that repository. For various reasons I need the file to be made available locally, within my Github. I also need my Github to stay current with any changes made in Gitlab.

How do we set something up such that every edit made to the file in Gitlab is automatically pushed to a copy of that file in Github?

I've tried mirroring the Gitlab repository as a whole, which would be overkill but would work - but unfortunately doing so replaces the entire contents of my Github.

Answer (score 1):

You could setup a [GitLab pipeline](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/) which, on every push (say in the `main` branch for instance), would:

- check if the file has been updated
- [clone the GitHub repository](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/how-to-clone-a-github-repo-as-part-of-pipeline/69689)
- update the file, add, commit and push.

I would recommend adding and committing the file (in the GitHub repository) using a dedicated branch (reserved just for that scenario).
That way, collaborators on GitHub side can decide when to merge that special branch and update their own version of the file.